# Validate an audio file

Tags: php

Is there any built-in function in PHP to validate an audio file except comparing MIME types, which can easily be invalid, because who says user uploads it only using a web-browser, anyone can make custom uploader sending let's say MIME type as audio/mpeg even though it's an EXE.

Or do I really have to compare magic numbers of each file?

Let's say I would accept only mp3,ogg,wav,mka,wma,mp4 (m4a) to be uploaded.

Comment: There are thousands of audio formats. Please narrow it down to fewer than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FileInfo extension. The mime types here are not provided by the client; they are figured out by the `FileInfo` extension. The mime types are figured out by looking at the contents of the file (often the first few bytes of the file, but some file formats need a little more analysis).

So, if a file is recognized as an audio file then it cannot be an executable. It may be an executable with an audio file signature, but audio players will not execute it; they will just read the file and treat it as audio data (and most likely give you an error saying that the file is corrupted).

I am not sure to what extent the extension looks at the file, but I a pretty sure it does as little as it can get away with. In other words, it most likely does not go through the entire file, checking that it is 100% valid. In order to do that to all the file formats you are allowing, you would need more heavy-duty programs, and probably at least a dedicated server. Unless you *absolutely need to be 100% sure* of a file's validity, doing a cursory check, like here, should be enough.

```
$file = '/path/to/file.mp3';

$info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type = $info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));

switch ($type) {
    case 'audio/mpeg':
        echo 'MP3!';
    break;
    case 'audio/ogg':
        echo 'OGG!';
    break;
    case 'audio/wav':
        echo 'WAV!';
    break;
    case 'audio/x-matroska':
        echo 'MKA!';
    break;
    case 'audio/mp4':
        echo 'MP4!';
    break;
    default:
        die('Format not supported!');
    break;
}
```