# Laravel keep rejecting m4a audio format, how to fix it?

Tags: validation, laravel, m4a

For the life of me, I just cannot figure out how to allow m4a audio file to pass through with laravel validation

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'audio' => 'required|mimes:mpga,mp3,mp4a,aac,m4a'
]);
```

The mp3, mpeg files can be uploaded successfully, but just keep rejecting m4a.

Anyone know which mime type should I include?

To be clear, I'm looking for the guess extension of Audio/x-m4a. All of these (m4a, mp4a, mp4, aac) does not seem to work.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455311/validate-an-audio-file

Comment: I checked that, the answer does not contain m4a

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am stuck with a similar .m4a problem, when I do `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)` on the file I get `audio/x-m4a` as a result, but when I add `audio/x-m4a'` to the Validator `mimes` list it still fails!!!!

Comment: Yea, it is really annoying. I think I just end up checking the mime type for m4a through finfo() separately by extending the mimes checker. If you dig through the supported Symfony list on audio file, m4a was never supported as audio. It's not even the fault of Laravel....

Comment: FYI, in case you need to find out the specific support for application/audio/video/etc. `MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php` from Symfony which Laravel extends from will be a good start to look at.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.4, try this: 
Change `mimes` to `mimetypes` and use `audio/x-m4a` instead of `m4a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you `dd` the file mime type like `$this->file('contract_copy')->guessExtension();` it will return something `"mp4a"` for `m4a` extension.

So I think you need `mp4a` extension in validation instead of `m4a` like,

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'audio' => 'required|mimes:mpga,mp3,mp4a,aac,mp4a'
]);
```

**For more:** check the validator class file in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php` there you can see how laravel validate against the mime-types.

```
protected function validateMimes($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    if (! $this->isAValidFileInstance($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $value->getPath() != '' && in_array($value->guessExtension(), $parameters);
}
```

Comment: If i do finfo_file() on the m4a file, it shows the extension m4a. I did put in mp4a as part of my question and m4a both. I took some sleep, and I'm wondering if it is quick time m4a file. Yet, I did put AAC as m4a. I even went as far as mp4 to be sure.

Comment: audio/x-m4a to be exact

Comment: Do you have a better answer to this? As the OP mentioned, he already included `mp4a` in his Validator, I have been too and can't come up with an answer.