# Laravel validate iOS recorded voice

Tags: laravel, mime, laravel-validation

I have put some `mime` type validation on my Laravel controller to validate received file from mobile applications:

```
'file' => 'required_without:body|file|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,mp3,mp4,pdf,doc,docx,m4a'
```

This validation rule is OK for most of files, but when iOS app sends recorded voice, this validation rule doesn't work.

Based on what `iOS` developer says, the file's mime type is `audio/m4a` but laravel (or maybe PHP) can't detect that.

I checked that `$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension()` returns `audio/m4a` but `$request->file('file')->guessExtension()` function returns null!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317180/6449040

Comment: I checked that. Not working. In my case guessExtension method returns null and when I remove my validation rule, file is saved with no extension!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did and I believe it is a good practice:

After some tracing that what laravel does to guess mimetypes, I noticed that it is registering some ExtensionGuesser classes like `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php` and there was no `audio/m4a` mimetype.

I provided `AnotherMimeTypeExtensionGuesser` containing:

```
protected $defaultExtensions = array(
    'audio/m4a' => 'm4a',
    'audio/x-m4a' => 'm4a',
    'audio/mp4' => 'm4a',
);
```

And then I registered it in my `AppServiceProvider` like this:

```
ExtensionGuesser::getInstance()->register(new AnotherMimeTypeExtensionGuesser);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this rule in your validation

```
'file' => 'required_without:body|file|mimetypes:audio/mp4|mimes:m4a'
```

Comment: I used this rule but not working yet: `mimes:mp3,mp4,mpga,m4a|mimetypes:audio/mp4,audio/m4a,audio/x-m4a`

Comment: The weird thing is that guessExtension method returns null!

Comment: Have you `dd($request->file('file'));` if not then do and show me the result